# What is the DFT of DFT of discrete signal

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, dft

What is the discrete fourier transform of the discrete fourier transform of any discrete time signal. Is result same signal? How?

Answer (score 5):

let

$$\begin{align}
 X[k] &= \mathcal{DFT} \Big\{ x[n] \Big\} \\
      &\triangleq \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] \, e^{-j2\pi nk/N}
\end{align} $$

and

$$ y[n] \triangleq X[n]  $$

(note the substitution of $n$ in for $k$.)  then

$$ Y[k] = \mathcal{DFT} \Big\{ y[n] \Big\} $$

then, if the DFT is defined the most common way (as above):

$$ Y[n] = N \cdot x[-n] $$

where periodicity is implied:  $x[n+N]=x[n]$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but can we use any property of DFT to find this solution?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how the DFT implementation or equation is scaled and indexed.  The result of dft(dft(x)) is to circularly reverse the array x (of length N) around its first element, possibly with a scale factor of N, 1/N, or 1/sqrt(N).

Computationally, there may also be added numerical or quantization noise (for instance, to the imaginary components if they were originally all zero for strictly real input).

Comment: shouldn't matter how it's indexed (as best as i can understand it).  you're certainly correct about the scaling, hot.